# Histogram of an Image's "Black Ink Level" by Horizontal Axis

Tags: python, linux, image-processing, imagemagick, gnuplot

I have a black and white image (or pdf) file, and want to get a histogram of the image's horizontal profile.  That is, for each column in the image I want the sum of the grayscale values of the pixels in the column.  If the image is X by Y pixels, I will end up with X numbers between 0 (for an entirely black column) and 255*Y (for an entirely white column).

Please see the second panel of [this comic](http://xkcd.com/688/)
[image: Comic]

I would like a histogram like this, but each bin would represent all the 'black ink' in the image at that x-coordinate (pixel).

As a poor graduate student, I'm constrained by using only the Linux command line, FOSS programs (ImageMagick, gnuplot, Perl, g++, etc).  Something like the GIMP would only be helpful if I can run the command via terminal, as I won't have access to a GUI.  A visual output file would be helpful for later, but is not necessary.

Does anyone know a way I can extract this information?  Searches for "image profile" just lead to information on color profiles.

Comment: Do you have python (and the Image module) available?

Comment: If it's free I can get it.  I tried learning Python years ago, but none of the syntax stuck without something to work on; this could be my inaugural project (typing `python` takes me to a `>>>` prompt).

Comment: OK, cool.  What OS are you using?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I will give an answer in two acts, using two of my favorite free utilities: python and gnuplot.

As a fellow (computational) graduate student, my advice is that if you want to do things for free python is one of the most versatile tools you can learn to use.

Here's a python script that does the first part, counting the grayscale value (from 0 for white to 255 for black):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Image            # basic image processing/manipulation, just what we want

im = Image.open('img.png')       # open the image file as a python image object
with open('data.dat', 'w') as f: # open the data file to be written
    for i in range(im.size[0]):  # loop over columns
        counter = sum(im.getpixel((i,j)) for j in range(im.size[1]))
        f.write(str(i)+'\t'+str(counter)+'\n')  # write to data file
```

Shockingly painless!  Now to have gnuplot make a histogram*:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

set terminal pngcairo size 925,900
set output 'plot.png'
#set terminal pdfcairo
#set output 'plot.pdf'
set multiplot

## first plot
set origin 0,0.025              # this plot will be on the bottom
set size 1,0.75                 # and fill 3/4 of the whole canvas

set title "Black count in XKCD 'Self-Description'"
set xlabel 'Column'
set ylabel "Black\ncount" norotate offset screen 0.0125

set lmargin at screen 0.15      # make plot area correct size
set rmargin at screen 0.95      # width = 740 px = (0.95-0.15)*925 px

set border 0                    # these settings are just to make the data
set grid                        # stand out and not overlap with the tics, etc.
set tics nomirror
set xtics scale 0.5 out 
set ytics scale 0

set xr [0:740]                  # x range such that there is one spike/pixel

## uncomment if gnuplot version >= 4.6.0
## this will autoset the x and y ranges
#stats 'data.dat'
#set xr [STATS_min_x:STATS_max_x+1]
#set yr [STATS_min_y:STATS_may_y]

plot 'data.dat' with impulse notitle lc 'black'

## second plot
set origin 0,0.75               # this plot will be on top
set size 1,0.25                 # and fill 1/4 of the canvas

unset ylabel; unset xlabel      # clean up a bit...
unset border; unset grid; unset tics; unset title

set size ratio -1               # ensures image proper ratio
plot 'img.png' binary filetype=png with rgbimage

unset multiplot         # important to unset multiplot!
```

To run these scripts, save them in the same directory with the image you want to plot (in this case the XKCD comic, which I saved as `img.png`).  Make them executable.  In bash this is

```
$ chmod 755 grayscalecount.py plot.plt
```

Then (if python+image module+gnuplot are all installed), you can run

```
$ ./grayscalecount.py
$ ./plot.plt
```

On my computer, running Ubuntu 11.10 with gnuplot 4.4.3, I get this cool plot at the end:

[image]

**Side note*: there are a lot of different histogram plots gnuplot can make.  I thought this style showed off the data well, but you can look into formatting your data for [gnuplot histograms](http://www.gnuplot.info/demo/histograms.html).

There are many ways to make python make plots itself or with gnuplot (matplotlib, pygnuplot, gnuplot-py), but I am not as facile with those.  Gnuplot is awesomely scriptable for plotting, and there are lots of ways to make it play nicely with python, bash, C++, etc.

Comment: You, Sir, are a model for the StackOverflow community.  I used your comment/hint from earlier and [Paul's good work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188104/pil-create-one-dimensional-histogram-of-image-color-lightness#4199541) with `plot "dataFile" using 1` and got something similar.  Thanks for your tip and your lucid, step-by-step, consolidated tutorial.  I hope the question is general enough to lead future Googlers to your answer.

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to stackoverflow!  I had a lot of fun coming up with that answer.

Comment: Very nice answer (+1).  I formatted your python code to make it PEP-8 compliant and I used a context manager to make sure the file gets properly flushed (Your old way didn't guarantee all of the data would actually be in the file when you exited the program because you didn't close the file).  I would advise the use of `sum` to remove the inner loop as well:  `sum(im.getpixel((i,j)) for j in range(im.size[1]))`.  If `im` support numpy like indexing, `sum(im[i,:])` would also work (but I don't know about that one since I don't usually use `Image`).

Comment: Thanks, @mgilson!  You taught me a couple of new things about python syntax which really make the script more compact and elegant.  I updated my answer.  I don't think image objects support numpy-style indexing, otherwise I would have put that in too.

Comment: @andyras -- I've learned a TON of cool python tricks by following the `python` tag on StackOverflow -- It gets a lot more traffic than `gnuplot` :).  I was also happy when you mentioned `pygnuplot` above -- although recently I started playing with `matplotlib` a little bit.  It'd pretty nifty as well (not that I plan on giving up pygnuplot any time soon!)

Comment: Isn't your 'black count' actually counting white?

Comment: @Junuxx, you're right, it's really counting 'white' values.  In the way grayscale information is stored, the range is from 0 (black) to 255 (white).  Since my python script performs a simple sum of the grayscale values, the more white in a column the higher the number.  I gave it the title 'black count' because user1717828 made reference to counting the amount of black in each bin, and I thought no one would notice :)

Comment: For the record, the `import sys` is completely useless here. You do _not_ need to import anything to call `open`.

Comment: Good point--probably a remnant from an earlier write of the script. Edited.

Comment: I just want to say I think it's amazing you are still editing/updating this answer some three years later.